# How do I change value names to numbers in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 10k movie names and 40k actor names.

[image]

The reason is I'm trying to make a graph from nx but the graphic becomes unreadable because of the names of the actor. So I want to change their names to numbers. Some of these actors played on multiple movies which means they are exists more than once. I want to change all these actors to numbers like 'Leslie Howard' = '1' and so on. I tried some loops and lists but I failed. I want to make a dictionary to be able to check which number was which actor. Can you help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all unique names of the column, generate a dictionary and then use `map` to change the values to the numbers. At the same time you have the dictionary to check to which actor the number refers.

```
all_names = df['Actor_Name'].unique()
dic = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(all_names))

df['Actor_Name'] = df['Actor_Name'].map(dic)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted but it returns Series.

Comment: updated it. now your column in the df gets changed

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `factorize`

```
df['Movie_name'] = df['Movie_name'].factorize()[0]
df['Actor_name'] = df['Actor_name'].factorize()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column into type *category* and get their unique values with `.cat.codes`:

```
df['Actor_Name'] = df['Actor_Name'].astype('category').cat.codes
```